# How to add header to checkout page on magento 2 LUMA theme

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, luma-theme, checkout-page

I have headers on all the pages in the LUMA theme except the checkout one. For reference, screenshots are attached below.
[image]

As you can see in the attached images, we have a header on the product view page, and it's missing on the checkout page? Is there any default way of adding it without overriding the module?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove layout="checkout" in page layout.xml in your theme 
Default checkout page magento in luma theme doesn't show header

Example

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body></body>
</page>
```

remove layout="checkout" then header will show up

Comment: This will add and footer

Comment: not working.............

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy:

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml
```

in your theme:

```
/app/design/frontend/**YourVendor**/**YourTheme**/Magento_Checkout/page_layout/checkout.xml
```

Checkout.xml need looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
            <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

And then just move logo in your **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
/app/design/frontend/**YourVendor**/**YourTheme**/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Content of **checkout_index_index.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Good luck and don't forget **Flush Cache** ;)

PS. **Main Navigation** is hidden with CSS by default Luma style. You need override CSS to.